# Get parameter type of generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

TypeScript has the utility type `Parameters` that gives the parameter type of a function, like this:

```
function simple(a: number, b: string) {}

type SimpleParameters = Parameters<typeof simple>;
// is: [a: number, b: string]
```

How can I do the same for a generic function? This doesn't work:

```
function generic<T>(a: T, b: string) {}

type GenericParameters = Parameters<typeof generic>;
// expected: <T>[a: T, b: string]
// actual: [a: unknown, b: string]
```

And this won't even compile:

```
type GenericParameters<T> = Parameters<typeof generic<T>>;
```

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks for the link! You're right, my question is a duplicate. I've flagged it for closing.